# Pandas - set numeric value from a JSON as float with 4 digits precision

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading data from a JSON file, which is in float format like `13.4567`.

The problem is that when I load it in Pandas, when I print that field I get the scientific notation like `1.34567e+06`.

Is there a way to set the field as regular float with 4 digits precision,as in the JSON source file, when I create the dataframe? Or do I have to massage the data after create the datafile?

This is the code used to load the JSON:

```
with open('myjson.json') as f:
    loaded_file = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(loaded_file), orient='column')

print(df.result)
```

The data file looks like this:

```
[
  {
      "info" : {
         "timestamp" : "2018-01-22 00:04:00.637000",
         "commit_hash" : "234234fdsfk3"
      },
      "action" : {
         "time_sec" : 14.7584,
         "diff" : 12345.375,
      }
   },
  {
      "info" : {
         "timestamp" : "2018-01-22 01:04:00.543000",
         "commit_hash" : "23eqdasfdsfk3"
      },
      "action" : {
         "time_sec" : 12.3456,
         "diff" : 543546.2234,
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], it isn't easy to figure out what the problem is from your description

Comment: Thanks, added the code I use to load the JSON file.

Comment: And the data? I'd like to see 5-10 records/rows of your file.

Comment: pasting the data too

Comment: I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: just pasted; I do not have multiple records yet; just trying the structure to create pandas filters

Comment: Doing `df = json_normalize(loaded_file)` works for me and looks fine.

Comment: So you get the number correctly formatted, instead of the scientific notation when you print the dataset? I am using Python3 on OSX Sierra

Comment: So the problem is print formatting? like `print(f"{df.result:2.6f}"`?

Comment: I see, so the data I see when I print is not what is in the dataframe field but the interpretation that the print command give to that value?

Comment: I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/moV1K.png

Comment: Indeed changing the print call to make it a float does the trick; I did learn something new today

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.4f}'.format
```

or

```
pd.set_option('display.precision',4)
```

this will set pandas do set the display formatting of your floats. 
If you really want to specifically to round the numbers, you would need to round the columns, since importing will automatically detect the dtype as a float, which comes with a default precision. Unless you are required to format the float for anything else than printing, which seems to be the case here, I would stick with display/printing formatting.